# Grilla editable con Jquery y PHP

Tags: php, jquery, grid

He desarrollado un formulario en PHP con varios campos. Todos ellos de tipo casilla de texto o casillas desplegables. Necesito agregar un nuevo campo de tipo "tabla".

Dentro de la base de datos lo almacenaré como un array o XML. Este será el formato del formulario (observen el campo Team)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que estoy buscando es un componente JQuery que permita tener una tabla editable:

- Permita eliminar, agregar o modificar en línea
- Diseño responsable
- Posibilidad de ser cargada desde un string en formato array o XML o similar
- Posibilidad de ser exportada a una string que se almacene en un campo de la base.

Estuve varias horas investigando y hay muchas opciones. Me gustaría alguna recomendación, pensando en un componente:

- Código abierto
- De uso común con PHP
- Estable
- Liviano

¿Alguien puede recomendarme qué es lo que se usa comunmente?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque busca recomendaciones de software. Además la pregunta no incluye código y "resultados" de su búsqueda sobre alternativas.

Answer (score 1):

Para todo lo visual el mas rapido es https://datatables.net/ tiene las opciones de ordenar,esconder columnas,editar,exportar a excel y varias cosas mas inclusive es responsiva

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar los DataTables de Metronic, ya incluyen todas las opciones del CRUD y otras herramientas como paginado, cantidad de registros y search.

Sólo tienes que incluir el JavaScript en la vista, colocar la tabla con id del tipo datatable e inicializarlo.

Aquí tienes un link para que veas los resultados http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_4/table_datatables_managed.html y aqui puedes descargar los js https://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/#undefined

Comment: Ya habías respondido antes, edita dicha respuesta y no agregues una respuesta nueva, por favor.